# Recursively calling game classes in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a game GUI for fun utilizing dice rolls. The code looks something like this:

```
public class run {
    //set up frame
    Game game = new Game();
    game.run();
}

public class Game {

    public void run() {
         Round round = new Round();
         int playerWhoLostADie = round.run();

         //handle if the game ends
         //otherwise, call recursively
         run(playerWhoLostADie);
    }
}

public class Round {

    public int run() {
         Turn turn = new Turn();
         Bet bet = turn.run();

         //if the round is over
         return(currentPlayer);
         //otherwise, call recursively
         run(bet);
    }
}

public class Turn {

    public Bet run() {
         //handle betting
         return bet;
    }
}
```

Is calling rounds and turns recursively an intelligent way to do this? Should I be using separate threads in order to avoid freezing the GUI, and if so, how?

Comment: No, whatever you do, do **not** use recursion for any of this. And there's likely no need to use threads directly. Simply use a Swing Timer.

Comment: I'm familiar with using Timers for delayed tasks. How would you recommend using them in this case?

Comment: I don't see any way to give specific advice with what you've posted, only general advice as I've given. If you want a more specific answer, you're going to need to ramp up the quality of the information posted including giving us a much better idea of your program structure, and more helpful code -- a [mcve] to be precise.

Answer (score -1):

Why use recursion to implement the turns from the game? I would go with a solution like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.run();
    }

}


public class Game {

    public void run() {
        boolean gameOver = false;

        while (!gameOver) {
            Round round = new Round();
            int playerWhoLost = round.run();

            /* if the game ends, then gameOver = true */
        }
    }

}


/* other classes related to the Game */
```